# Edit the css for time range buttons for Range Slider and Selector In Plotly

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, plotly

I am wanting to edit the css for the buttons in this example
https://plotly.com/javascript/range-slider/

[image: original buttons]

To look like this:
[image: desired outcome]

I have a scss file with the class .selector-rect
but the css I add to it does not alter it correctly. Any tips on how to edit the CSS for them?
Thanks.

Comment: Just use "!important" on your css statements. Because the element has inline style, which has higher priority than your external css file, your css style doesn't show. Then it is straight forward to get what you wanted. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Could you show us the CSS you are trying to add. Also how are you changing 6m to 6mon?